# How to draw a very big BufferedImage on a fixed size JPanel?

Tags: jpanel, repaint

I add a jpanel on a JFrame. And I implement the jpanel like this.

`class MyPanel extends JPanel
{
    private BufferedImage image;`

```
public MyPanel(BufferedImage img)
{
    this.image = img;
}
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);

    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), this);
    System.out.println("draw image");
    g.dispose();
}
void update(BufferedImage image){
    this.image=image;       
    repaint();
}
```

}

I want that everytime I call the update method ,new image can be drawn on the panel.

But an image is too big that only partial of it is on the panel. What do I need to do next?

BTW , I've tried to use the JScrollPane with JPanel ,but it didnt work. Does anybody can

help? Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you want to scale the image, or do you want to display the unscaled image in a scroll pane?

Comment: @DavidTanzer I wanna an unscaled image on a scroll pane.